# ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.64 not available for download. Selenium could not start a new session

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use a Java script with Selenium.

I have installed in a Mac Google Chrome Version 101.0.4951.64 but there is not available this version for ChromeDriver

[Chromedriver Chromium Downloads](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

And I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session.

Response code 500. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Also, there is a ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.27 but I can not get Chrome version 102 to download.

I already solved my issue using WebDriverManager which auto download the needed driver, I don't delete the question and my solution because it could help others.

Comment: ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41 should be the one to use. But it doesn't work, there is a random crash ending with "20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6e537b8b thread_start + 15". No solution at the moment... I'm going to try with google chrome beta (102). Please let me know if you find any solution to this issue.

Comment: @ColinBernet I read somewhere that minor versions will work for previous patches (Semantic Versioning) so for instance ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.64 will work for  Chrome Version 101.0.4951.41.
But in this case you are saying that previous patches should be the one to use (I think it's not guaranteed to work, and in my case it's not working).
I have been using WebDriverManager without issues in the last days.

Comment: @ColinBernet using WebDriverManager I see in the logs that under the hood is using ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41, so I have no idea why my code works using it and it not works using ChromeDriver 101.0.4951.41 from my Mac.